# Search a series of contiguous row cells in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Search a series of contiguous row cells in a worksheet

```
    h1 h2 h3 h4 h5             h1 h2 h3 h4 h5
    1  2  3  6  7              1  2  3  8  9
    2  2  2  4  5              3  3  3  2  1
    table 1                    table 2
```

How do i code a loop to search the first three cells in each row of table2, in table 1? given that the tables have the same format.

Range and cells dont seem to do the work because i cant use counter with them

Comment: You need to be more specific - do all three cells have to match, or what?

Comment: So yeah i start with choose 1 2 3 (only these three values)and search for it in every row in table 1, it matches if it is the exact same value and exact same order(like row 1 in table 1) @Tim Williams

Comment: And then i do the same thing for every row in table 2 @ Tim Williams

Comment: Same values in the same order *and* in the same position (first 3 columns)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim tlb1 as range,tbl2 as range
dim rw1 as range, rw2 as range

set tbl1=Range("your table1 range here")
set tbl2=Range("your table2 range here")

for each rw1 in tbl1.rows
    for each rw2 in tbl2.rows
        if rw1.cells(1)=rw2.cells(1) and rw1.cells(2)=rw2.cells(2) _
           and rw1.cells(3)=rw2.cells(3) then
           'do whatever you want to do on match...
           'Exit For 'if you want to stop when you find the first match...
        end if
    next rw2
next rw1
```

Comment: This looks great. How would I modify this if the rows i'm comparing are not on the same row lvl? As in maybe row2 in tbl1 matches row1 in table 2. @TimWilliams

Comment: Did you try it?  Should already check every row in table 1 against every row in table 2.